# Set permissions based on user permissions

Tags: permissions, find, chmod

Because of the default umask settings on my systems, file permissions always default to no access for group and other.  This is fine typically but annoying when I'm installing software that I need others to access.  Is there a quick way I can reset permissions of all files and folders in a tree after an install based on the use permissions.

Basically copy user except for write.

```
rwx------ to rwxr-xr-x
rw------- to rw-r--r--
```

Comment: You need to use `--recursive` option.

Comment: Why not just change the umask setting from the default to something you like _before_ you do the install?

Comment: @John1024 Even better.

Comment: I thought of that while I was typing this question, but the damage is already done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` to do this :

```
find <dirpath> -perm 700 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  ## For directories
find <dirpath> -perm 600 -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  ## For files
```

Comment: You could also add the "-perm 600" and "-perm 700" if you wanted to only modify the files with the permissions mentioned in the initial question;

`find <dirpath> -perm 700 -type d -exec chmod  755 {} \;`
`find <dirpath> -perm 600 -type f -exec chmod  644 {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
find . ! -type l -print0 |
  perl -0 -lne '
    $m = (lstat$_)[2] & 07777;
    $u = ($m >> 6) & 5;
    chmod $m | $u | ($u<<3), $_'
```

That is, take the user permissions, remove the *write* bit (`& 5`) and *or* that to the *group* and *other* permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're a well behaved unix user and don't have whitespaces in filenames:

```
for file in $(find . -type f -o -type d)
do \
    user_perm=$(stat -c %a $file |cut -c1)
    other_perm=$(($user_perm&5))
    chmod $user_perm$other_perm$other_perm $file
done
```

Comment: It's not only whitespace, it's any character in `$IFS` and wildcards

Comment: That expects the GNU implementation of `stat`. Note that GNU `find` can output that same information by itself (`-printf '%m'`)

Comment: That approach won't work for files with no user permissions or files with setuid/setgid/stickybit...